# PLSQL - Trigger not responding

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a problem with my trigger. The trigger's purpose is to update a stock ("STOCK") from a product ("Artigo") when it has been placed in a bill line ("Linha_Fatura_Encomenda") from a bill ("Fatura_Encomenda"). When I place a product in the bill, the quantity ("QUANTIDADE") should be verified to make sure that the stock can cover it, but this is not happening.

```
create or replace TRIGGER stock_disponivel_check
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF QUANTIDADE ON LINHA_FATURA_ENCOMENDA
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  STOCK   INTEGER;
  Value_out_of_range  EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (Value_out_of_range, -4096);

BEGIN
  UPDATE ARTIGO 
    SET STOCK = STOCK - :NEW.QUANTIDADE
    WHERE STOCK > 0;

  IF (STOCK = 0 OR STOCK <0) THEN
    RAISE Value_out_of_range;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN Value_out_of_range THEN
    Raise_application_error (
      -20300,
      'Stock '|| TO_CHAR(STOCK) ||' inexistente!'
    );
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20322, 'Nenhum Valor Introduzido!');
END;
```

Any thoughts on that?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename you local variable and return the value of STOCK field into this variable (there can be only zero or one row to update otherwise it will fail)

```
DECLARE
  L_STOCK   INTEGER;
  Value_out_of_range  EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (Value_out_of_range, -4096);

BEGIN
  UPDATE ARTIGO 
    SET STOCK = STOCK - :NEW.QUANTIDADE
    WHERE STOCK > 0
  RETURNING STOCK INTO L_STOCK;

  IF (L_STOCK = 0 OR L_STOCK < 0) THEN
    RAISE Value_out_of_range;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN Value_out_of_range THEN
    Raise_application_error (
      -20300,
      'Stock '|| TO_CHAR(L_STOCK) ||' inexistente!'
    );
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20322, 'Nenhum Valor Introduzido!');
END;
```